# Permission denied moving files

Tags: permissions, clipboard

Extreme noob here so please point me in the direction for beginners!

I have managed to mount my Box.net account following [these instructions](http://www.liberiangeek.net/2012/03/automatically-mount-box-cloud-storage-in-ubuntu-12-04-11-10/).

However when I copy files and paste them into a file within box I get a permission denied error message. Then I try again and it will let me move it.  However it keeps happening and is making batch movements impossible.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: How did you copy? Via nautilus? Permission denied errors only means one thing, you don't have the right privileges to access the file. Try to run `gksu nautilus` in the terminal to open nautilus as root and copy the files again, or you can copy on via terminal with `sudo cp source_path target_location`. Alternatively, you can also take ownership of the directory by running `sudo chown username:username dir_path`.

Comment: I guess the author from your link might have  forgotten  to use `sudo` infront of the command `gedit ~/.davfs2/secrets`. Try adding sudo and try again

Comment: Thanks for your help, will have a try and get back to you.

Answer (score 2):

Unfortunately i can not access your link. So i can not see any command you used. Don't confuse with permission. There are two things, permission and owner. Sometimes permission auto change when we copy some folder or file from pendrive or somewhere. That is because, when your system found any harmful or not recognized executable file it changes the permission immediately so the file failed to run. It's fully security issue. But sometimes Beginner user face this problem and get bored with it.

If your folder permission change then right click on it, you will see this..
[image]

You can see three group, "Owner , Group, Other". Just change the permission as you need. Sometimes you will see like this..

[image]

Something different here !! Owner is root not you. So you can not change permission from here.
You can change permission using terminal also

```
chmod 775 /media/folder/folder
three number : owner permission=7, group permission=5, other permission=5
write permission=4, read permission=2, execute permission=1
```

It only work if you are the owner of the file or folder. But what happen if you are not the owner? Don't worry, take the root's power, use "sudo"

```
sudo chmod 775 /media/folder/folder
```

And last one, how to change ownership

```
sudo chown your_usrname:your_username /media/folder/folder
```

Comment: Thanks all for you input, will try all of the above and see if they help.  First I will need to figure out half of what is written as this is all very new to me.